# jqGrid trigger reload does not work

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, reload

Hi I am new to jqGrid and I have gone through many posts in the forum trying to reload the data on the grid from the server when I click on a button (search button). But it's only done once. Can someone help?

```
<div id="resultGrid">
   <table id="datagrid"></table>
</div>
<div id="navGrid"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#datagrid").jqGrid({
            url: 'Home/GridData',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'POST',
            postData: {
                phone: function () { return $("#PhoneTextBox").val(); },
                email: function () { return $("#EmailTextBox").val(); }
            },
            colNames: ['PNR', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'CountryCode', 'Phone', 'Email', 'Type', 'Action'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'pnr', index: 'pnr', width: 55, editable: false, editoptions: { readonly: true, size: 10 } },
                { name: 'firstname', index: 'firstname', width: 80, editable: false, editoptions: { readonly: true, size: 10 } },
                { name: 'lastname', index: 'lastname', width: 80, editable: false, editoptions: { readonly: true, size: 10 } },
                { name: 'countrycode', index: 'countrycode', width: 100, align: "right", editable: true, editoptions: { readonly: true, size: 10 } },
                { name: 'phone', index: 'phone', width: 80, align: "right", editable: false, editoptions: { readonly: true, size: 10 } },
                { name: 'email', index: 'email', width: 80, align: "right", editable: false, editoptions: { readonly: true, size: 10 } },
                { name: 'type', index: 'type', width: 80, align: "right", editable: false, editoptions: { readonly: true, size: 10 } },
                {
                    name: 'edit', index: 'edit', width: 80, sortable: false,
                    formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                        return "<input style='width:60px;' type='button' value='Edit' " +
                               "onclick=\"editRow(" + options.rowId + ");\" />";
                    }
                }

            ],
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40],
            sortname: 'no',
            sortorder: "asc",
            height: 210,
            gridview: true,
            viewrecords: true,
            caption: "TCD Search Results",
            jsonReader: {
                total: "total",
                page: "page",
                records: "records",
                root: "rows"
            },
            gridComplete: resetjson()
        });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#SearchContact").click(function () {
            alert($("#PhoneTextBox").val());
            $("#datagrid").trigger('reloadGrid');
        });
    });

    function resetjson() {

        $("#datagrid").setGridParam({ datatype: 'json', url: 'Home/GridData' }).trigger("reloadGrid");

    }

    function editRow(i) {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'Home/EditRow',
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function () {
                alert('Success');
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

The code on the server side looks like:

```
public ActionResult GridData(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows, string phone, string email)
    {
        if (phone.Equals("5"))
        {
            var jsonData = new
            {
                total = 1, // we'll implement later 
                page = page,
                records = 3, // implement later 
                rows = new[] {
                    new {id = 1, cell = new[] {"1", "-7", "abcd"}},
                    new {id = 2, cell = new[] {"2", "15", "efgh"}},
                    new {id = 3, cell = new[] {"3", "23", "jklm"}}
                }
            };
            return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            var jsonData = new
            {
                total = 1, // we'll implement later 
                page = page,
                records = 3, // implement later 
                rows = new[] {
                    new {id = 1, cell = new[] {"1", "2", "tbir"}},
                    new {id = 2, cell = new[] {"2", "4", "mr"}},
                    new {id = 3, cell = new[] {"3", "6", "pd"}}
                }
            };
            return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);            
        }
    }
```

Comment: The grid is initially loading fine for you on page load?

Comment: Yes it's initially loading fine. I can also get a refresh if I page. But if I try to click on Search button in order to pass new search data the server side code is not called anymore! I am in real need of figuring this out and having been at it for 3 days now!

Comment: What happens when you click the search button? Does the search window come up but just yields no results? Do you see any 'undefined' labels/errors anywhere?

Comment: Also, your `sortname: 'no',` does not match any column indexes. See http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me.All labels are fine. I have a few html text boxes (phone, email, etc.) and a button. These are outside jqGrid. So what I want to happen is to click the search button and post the data to the backend where I will get a fresh set of data for the grid based on user input of phone, email, etc. 
I put a breakpoint on the server side. When the Grid loads I get to the server side and execution stops. However at this point phone, email are empty. Now I type in "5" for phone number and click Search button. But nothing happens. I don't get to the backend anymore!

Comment: by the way I fixed the sort column but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this forum post (http://forums.asp.net/t/1814027.aspx/1),
it suggests that:

```
postData: {
    phone: function () { return $("#PhoneTextBox").val(); },
    email: function () { return $("#EmailTextBox").val(); }
},
```

should have keywords in quotes, like this:

```
postData: {
    'phone': function () { return $("#PhoneTextBox").val(); },
    'email': function () { return $("#EmailTextBox").val(); }
},
```

Comment: I tried it with 'phone' and 'email' and it still did not refresh the grid.

Comment: Can someone post a simple and complete example of one textbox (let's say phone) and one button and a jqGrid where everytime the button is pressed the grid is refreshed? I would really appreciate that as I am in a bind to get this working.

Comment: One hint: everytime I put 
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
around my jqGrid, I get script error:

Unhandled exception at line 51, column 9 in http://localhost:15818/
0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected

Would this cause the problem? If I remove the     jQuery(document).ready(function () { 
line, the grid comes up and displays data (it still does not refresh).

Comment: I use jqGrid quite a bit and always initialize it inside jQuery(document).ready(function(){}).  So that's not good if you're getting errors when you do.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the call to resetjson() in an anonymous function?  i.e., `gridComplete: function(){ resetjson(); }`

Comment: Here is what's so curios:
    $("#datagrid").jqGrid({
        caption: "TCD Search Results",
        ....
    });
has no issues. But 
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#datagrid").jqGrid({
        caption: "TCD Search Results"
    });
});

0x800a01b6 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method error!!!

Comment: but I can wrap other jQuery functions in ready with no problems:

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#SearchContact").click(function () {
        alert("1");
    });

Comment: Got it! thank you for all your help. The problem was a conflict of jqueries. MVC4 puts a line to @render jquery in the layout page. I had to remove that. Thanks again. I am happy now :)